# How to fix connection refused error in Jedis in docker-compose?

Tags: java, docker, redis, docker-compose, jedis

i am setting docker-compose  with redis server and java application, when redis run inside docker-compose my code working fine
with outside java program in HOST OS .

but when i put java program inside container i am getting
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Redis-cli 127.0.0.1:6379> is also working fine

```
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
            this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
            startWorking();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

when use "redis" instead of "localhost" its give me unknown host error from outside docker-compose and connection refused inside docker-compose

this is my dockercompose.yml

```
 redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"

  worker:
    build: worker
```

Comment: Do you contenerize redis and java app in the same compose? If not they are not connected to the same network probably, that is why `redis` as redis host does not work.

Comment: yes in the same compose ...how can i configure redis host in docker-compose along with java-app.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying networks explicitly and adding `depends_on` to make sure redis is up when the worker needs it.

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  worker:
    build: worker
    networks:
      - net
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - net

networks:
  net:
```

Create the `jedis` instance with `new Jedis("redis", 6379);`.

You might want to read more about [networking in compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and [dependencies between services](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on).

You can also try running an example without compose and then transforming it to a compose configuration. Here is [an example of network configuration](https://github.com/Shpota/grpc-wallet) without docker compose.